# Работа с Webpack на готовом лендинге

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Есть свёрстанный адаптивный лендинг со стилями, скриптами, шрифтами и т.д. Недавно начал осваивать вебпак, настроил его конфиг, подключил все необходимые плагины/модули. Собирается без ошибок. Пример package.json и webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

if (!devMode) {
  plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8008,
    },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html'), // шаблон
      filename: 'index.html',
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```js
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
}
```

Вопрос: html-webpack-plugin создаёт шаблон страницы, а как мне начать работу со своим документом? Куда закинуть готовый index.html?:)
Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: в src создаеш свой.html
в template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/свой.html'), // шаблон

Comment: @Armen это было так очевидно, жаль сам не догадался :) Спасибо большое, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: незачто был рад помочь